# Migrating from sentry-raven to sentry-ruby and catch top level error

Tags: ruby, sentry

I have a simple ruby program not using (rails, rake, sidekiq...)

I would like to be able to capture errors from it using Sentry.

I was using the [legacy ruby client](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-ruby/tree/master/sentry-raven) `sentry-raven`:

```rb
require 'sentry-raven'

Raven.configure do |config|
  config.dsn = '...'
end

Raven.capture do
  1 / 0
end
```

I wanted to migrate to the new ruby client `sentry-ruby` but I could not find a way to do it using the migration guide. Is there an alternative to the following wrapper ?

```rb
require 'sentry-ruby'

Sentry.init do |config|
  config.dsn = '...'
end

begin
  1 / 0
rescue Exception => e
  Sentry.capture_exception(e)
  raise
end
```